# Logarithmic equations: Solving for the Variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The equation is $(3/2)\ln x= -2$. I am not sure how to work this one. If anyone could show all the steps that would be a great help. I tried working it out and got down to $x^{3/2}=e^{-2}$ that is probably wrong but if by some chance it is right what do you do after that?

Comment: Keep the $\ln x$ alone. Use the fact that $\exp(\ln x)=x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $x^{3/2}=e^{-2}$ is correct.  If you know $x^{3/2}=\text{something}$, then you can say
$$
\Big(x^{3/2}\Big)^{2/3} = \text{something}^{2/3}
$$
and then
$$
x^{(3/2)\cdot(2/3)} = \text{something}^{2/3}.
$$

Then remember how to simplify $\dfrac 3 2 \cdot \dfrac 2 3$.

Then you need to simplify $\displaystyle\Big(e^{-2}\Big)^{2/3}$.  That is similar to something done above.

Comment: Thank you so much! This clarifies everything!

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{3}{2} \ln x = -2 \iff \ln x = \frac{ -4}{3} \iff e^{-\frac{4}{3} }= x$$

Comment: Okay just a question, why would you not raise the x to (3/2)? My teacher said that is what we would do because it is a logarithm property.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{3}{2}\ln x=-2\\
\implies \ln x=\dfrac{-4}{3}\\
\implies \exp(\ln x)=\boxed{x=\exp\left(\dfrac{-4}{3}\right)}$$

Comment: "$=-2$" and not "$=-1$".

Comment: So do you multiply the (3/2) to the other side being the -2? and this is probably a stupid question but what does exp stand for?

Comment: @IlaIsabelle $$\exp(x)=e^x$$

Comment: Oh thank you!!!

Comment: @IlaIsabelle Sure!